# Multiple threads connecting to MBeanServer

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jmx

On the client side, the getAttribute() method of MBeanServerConnection is blocking code.
What will happen if multiple threads are using the same MBeanServerConnection and invoke getAttribute() for the purpose of getting multiple attributes at one time? Does MBean Server handle concurrent requests well and make it an effective and faster way to get multiple attributes of an MBean? I did not find in the docs whether getAttribute() is synchronized or not.

Comment: Every time you are not sure thread safe object or not it would be better to use synchronization. "Make it right, then make it fast"

Comment: Yes but I don't have to use synchronization for getAttribute() method if just connect to MBean server using a single thread. The reason I asked is that I am not sure how the underlying implementation of MBean server works to support multi threading. Most of the time is spent on network I/O if I need to get a lot of attributes.